# Android SQL Query - descending order thinks 50 is bigger than 100

Tags: android, mysql, sql, cursor

When I run the following query, I get unexpected results:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE };
    Cursor c = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_SCORE + " DESC", "10");
    String result = "";
```

So, this should sort the results by the KEY_SCORE column in my table, and sort them based on descending order. When I do this, I get the following results:

```
Mr Z - 72
Mr S - 70  
Mr A - 50
Mr B - 50
Mr T - 130
Mr X - 125
```

It therefore seems to be grouping the values in two different groups. One group of two digit entries, one group of three digit entries. I need them to all be together and therefore listed correctly with the highest number at the top of the list. I know I could workaround this by having it as 050, 070, but I would prefer a clean method of solving this (or a way of removing the 0 in 070 when the value from the database is printed to the screen).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you have the `KEY_SCORE` column defined in your table? Looks like a string type of some kind.

Comment: Define the key_score column as an int, not a string. That is a properly descending STRING ordering you've got there.

Comment: What's the type of the column? The string "50" is greater than the string "100", so will come first when ordering in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I really appreciate it!

That answers the first problem, but, if I want to sort them as int's in order of descending, how would I go about that? The query method needs a String for the orderBy section, how do I get around that? Sorry if that is confusing, I am somewhat confused by this!